# jQuery - Raphael - SVG - get location of elements with same data attribute into array

Tags: javascript, jquery, svg, raphael

I have assigned a custom data attribute to some circles added to the Raphael canvas as follows in a `each()` loop:

```
marker.data('transaction', transaction);
```

How do I find elements on the canvas that have the same transaction data value, and get their location into an array in a for loop, and then perform actions on that array?

For example in pseudo code:

```
for (current_transaction = 1; current_transaction < 10; current_transaction++) {
    var array = find the location of elements with transaction data value of 
    current transaction;
    //perform some function with that array
}
```

My question is really then, how do you 'getElementByData', and then search for elements with the same data. The rest is simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[document.querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/Document.querySelectorAll%20for%20more%20information)('[transaction]') would get everything with the attribute transaction.

Use [transaction='foo'] to get just transaction attributes having the value foo e.g.

```
<svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1">

  <path transaction="1"/>
  <path transaction="2"/>
  <path transaction="1"/>

  <script>
    for (var current_transaction = 1; current_transaction &lt; 2; current_transa
ction++) {
       var found = document.querySelectorAll("[transaction='" + current_transact
ion +"']");
       alert(found.length);
    }
  </script>

</svg>
```

Comment: No, current_transaction is a number so you're doing document.querySelectorAll(1)

Comment: var found = document.querySelectorAll('[transaction=current_transaction]');

Comment: Maybe current_transaction is a string so the first time it would be 1 and the second 11. alert(current_transaction) after the loop would tell you.

Comment: The current_transaction must be in additional quotes so it's 
var found = document.querySelectorAll("[transaction='" + current_transaction +"']");

Comment: Hmm, it still says the NodeList has length 0? Thanks for this btw - I've been at this 1 thing for hours